# How to find the distance from a point to a line in 3d using Lagrange's multipliers

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

I know how to find to determine the shortest distance from a point to a plane.I am curious if the same can be done for a line in 3d space.

Comment: How do you characterise the plane?

Comment: as $f(x,y,z)$=0

Comment: Yes. You just have two constraints $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$. The reason is that a line is intersection of two planes. So your point on the line is at the same time in both planes

Comment: thank you!One more thing if we are given the cartesian form of the line how do we find the planes that intersect to form the line

Comment: Well, a line can be characterised directly as some $t \mapsto p(t)$, so the problem reduces to the unconstrained problem $\min_t \|x_0-p(t)\|^2$.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to so, solve the nearest point problem or use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: There are infinitely many planes. Think of a door and the frame. The intersection line of the plane is the axis of the hinges. The axis is constant, no mater how much the door is opened. As @copper.hat mentioned, there is an easier way to solve the problem (no Lagrange multipliers), if the parametric equation of the line is given.

Comment: thank for the input, now I understand